# process started from service from same account but not in show process from all users, and cant access to network share

Tags: process, windows-services, share, network-share

I have windows service program that starts an exe process, and have another user interface
that can start same exe like service.

problem is when I start exe from UI, exe can access network share files and in task manager
can be viewed without checking the check box: **show processes from all users.**

but when start process from serivce, I can't see it in task manager list, and have to check
the checkbox I mentioned.

in both situation username tab in task manager is the same, but in start from service not listed 
without checking the checkbox.

I checked all 4 types in ProejctInstaller class from serivce project:

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService;
```

any idea?

Comment: I believe that the Task Manager checkbox is actually misleadingly labelled. It would be more accurately labelled as "show processes from all sessions" but since the norm is for each user to only be logged into a single interactive session, the distinction isn't normally apparent.

Comment: so what can I do? I can't access network share when start process from service, although I type the share address in cmd, I cant access the folder. and running from UI, no problem occurs, just start process from service has the problem :( :( :(

Comment: How are you trying to access the share? By drive letter or by UNC path (the latter is far more likely to work than the former)

Comment: like this: \\192.168.0.1\folder\